# latest update to oberdiek | auxhook.sty not found?

Tags: errors, miktex, missing, oberdiek

Just updated to the 20 December build of the obderdiek package, on my MikTex 64-bit installation. Files that compiled without problems are now throwing the following error:

```
 ! LaTeX Error: File 'auxhook.sty' not found.
```

What puzzles me is that this used to be part of the oberdiek bundle (or so I believe), but isn't now.

So, I pull down auxhool.dtx, and try a manual install (using MikTeX), and all seems to be running fine, except that it throws the same error -- 'auxhook.sty' not found.

I can always roll back, but...suggestions?  Thanks in advance...

Comment: Took the auxhook.sty from the \oberdiek subdirectory from the archived version I made before I updated, copied it into \oberdiek, refreshed the package database, and...it works fine (as far as I can tell). So, perhaps auxfile.sty was simply 'accidentally left out' of latest update to oberdiek?

Comment: `auxhook` and a bunch of others were removed from oberdiek to reduce the size of the (still huge) bundle. It's now a package of its own. See this list: https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.2500.1576667612.2586.ctan-ann@ctan.org

Comment: Not on the MikTeX repos it isn't. ;-) And, trying to manually install the auxhook.dtx the usual way (i.e., latex auxhook.dtx), fails...at least for me.

Comment: Well, tried again, using manual pull of latest and greatest from git, and this tiime, manual install worked. Still not on MikTeX repos, though.

Comment: This CTAN paragraph is confuse or explain the confusion: "If you install a minimal tex installation that previously installed oberdiek then to install the equivalent set of package's you may now need to install" ... follows a list of 50 packages.
Does that means that Oberdiek will be decomisioned and its functionality will be sustituted by other packages? And the packages that are based on Oberdiek, will not have problems?

Comment: @JohnnyCanuck I don't know about MiKTeX, but the packaging usually doesn't depend on the distribution. And the split was a couple of days ago, so it should already be available (especially since your oberdiek bundle is updated)

Comment: So, I just posted a question with the MikTex folks about this. It definitely isn't on the MikTeX repos (and yes, I refreshed the database on my install ;-) Further to the question, if obderdiek is going to be split up into 50+ individual packages (as queried), what a pain in the <insert favourite body part> that will be for users (easier for maintainers, perhaps...).

Comment: @djanvas oberdiek is a bundle of (dozens of) packages. In the last couple of weeks, some of the packages were removed from the bundle to make it more maintainable, each of which got a CTAN entry of its own. The bundle still exists and it's not planned to be further split, so it will remain for the time being. That sentence says that the former oberdiek bundle is now the reduced oberdiek bundle plus that list of packages.

Comment: @JohnnyCanuck I know :-) See the last few commits here: https://github.com/latex3/latex3/commits/master Though this should only be a problem for people with minimal TeXLive installations (such as the ones for automated tests, like the one in the link above). In my computer, with a full TeXLive I had no problem, and the automatic install of MiKTeX should also minimise the issue... If the package isn't there, then that's a bigger issue...

Comment: Will be fixed in the update tomorrow https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/151

Comment: I had this problem after updating today when calling the file hyperref.sty, which includes the line 132 "\RequirePackage{auxhook}[2009/12/14]". Will this be fixed in the update tomorrow as well, @moewe?

Comment: @JesusMartinezGarcia I can run a simple document with `hyperref` (that automatically loads `auxhook`) just fine after the update this morning. So this should be fixed.

Comment: @moewe Which repository do you use? auxhook does not appear as a package in ctan.cs.uu.nl and hyperref says it us updated (as of 21/12/2019).

Comment: @JesusMartinezGarcia My MikTeX console is configured to install from *a random package repository on the Internet*. According to the logs I got most data from http://packages.oth-regensburg.de/, http://ctan.space-pro.be and http://ftp.fau.de. The MikTeX side lists `auxhook` as a stand-alone package now (https://miktex.org/packages/auxhook), so if you pick a mirror that is up to date and update in both Admin and User mode, things should hopefully work. If that doesn't do it, go to *Tasks > Update package database* in Admin and User mode and try again.

Comment: Manual update did not work for me, either. I pick the latest auxhook from ctan, installed it to local repository, refreshed the file database (using MikTeX tools) and pdflatex stopped working with a error from microtype(?):
`251
pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable 
fonts.
\AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox 
                                                  \fi \fi 
l.251 \chapter
              {{FORORD} }`

Comment: @Sveinung A full update in Admin and User mode (and possibly *Tasks > Update package database* in Admin and User mode) should really be enough to get `auxhook` back on track again. I could not observe an error similar to the one you describe after the update. But in any case I guess it would be better to open a new question with an MWE about this.

Comment: @moewe It seems that that the last update crashed may font map file.